# ThisWorkBook.Names().Comment converts the reference from A1 to F1C1

Tags: excel, vba, comments, names

Adding a comment to a Name from the Names collection in Microsoft Excel renders the Name unusable. The weird thing is that it happens only sometimes, sometimes not, but it happens safely when running the code step by step with F8.

```
Option Explicit
'I AM MORE INTERESTED IN UNDERSTANDING THE REASON FOR THE ERROR THAN ALTERNATIVE SOLUTIONS!
Sub Test()
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Set My_Range = ActiveSheet.Range("N1:P17")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "DAILY_QUOTES_LME", My_Range.CurrentRegion
    'The following instruction, has a strange behavior, (it happens only sometimes);
    'But it happens safely when running step by step with F8.
    'This next line converts style reference A1 to F1C1 according to the name manager.
    ThisWorkbook.Names("DAILY_QUOTES_LME").Comment = Date 'Tag for update date.
    'The following statement produces an error 424 because the reference now has an F1C1 style.
    [DAILY_QUOTES_LME].Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = 14395790
End Sub
```

I leave some captures:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1elM0RTz92Tr5Ioe05MNq3iyi4ZLY11F4/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Vz854fYcknPZB4GsW5UkG2NSW3lgGob/view?usp=sharing
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Can't reproduce: US Win10 Excel V2101

Comment: Sorry, maybe I know why ShtDailyQuotes is the CodeName of my sheet; which if you replace by ActiveSheet, maybe you can reproduce it.

Comment: I was using ActiveSheet in my testing...

Comment: Tim Williams, The error occurs in Excel 2019 through 2007.

Comment: Can you share a workbook which reproduces the problem?  Via dropbox/onedrive/etc

Comment: Of course, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lhhP4d3DHjdeVqQ49LKZu6OmjVOJ07lS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on my PC (win10, Office365, US region)